# Problems implementing "Save" feature on website

Tags: php, sql, mysql, session

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$currentPage = $_POST["currentPage"];
$passedCoupID = $_POST["passedCoupID"];
/*
if youre logged in, save

if not, take you to the register page with an option to go right back to the coupon if you dont want to register

*/

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","admin","admin");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("users", $con);

if($_SESSION["loggedIn"] == 1)
    {
        $userID = $_SESSION["userID"];
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users_saves (userID, couponID) VALUES ('$userID', '$couponID')");
        mysql_select_db("coupons", $con);
        mysql_query("UPDATE stats SET saves = saves + 1 WHERE id = '$couponID'");
        header('Location: ' . $currentPage);
    }
else
    {
        header('Location: register.php');
        $_SESSION["goBack"] = $currentPage;
    }
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks the "Save" button on a page, it will go to this form, which will insert both the user's ID and the coupon's ID into the table `users_saves`. Then I want it to change databases and increment the row `saves` at the `id` of the saved coupon. It looks fine to me, and it works without errors, but it writes `0`, `0` to the table `users_saves` instead of either of the values, and I'm not sure why. Also, there is no increment of `saves` when I do the database switch.

Comment: Please also check out and use http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your variable seems to be called `$passedCoupID`, while in the sql you are referencing `$couponID`

that might be your problem right there. You should turn on all errors, then you'll probably see a lot of "notice" errors in your code.